# Remove all child elements from table except for first?

Tags: jquery

My HTML:

```
<table id="user-table">
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td></tr>     
</table>
```

How can I remove all child elements of the user-table except the first `<tr>` using jQuery?

What I've tried:

```
$("#user-table").children().remove();
```

However it removes all the child `<tr>` elements but I want the first row not to be removed.

Here's my jQuery so far:

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("../lib/ajax/add-user.php", $("#add-form").serialize(),
    function(data){ 
    javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();

    $("#user-table").children().remove();
    //$('#list-box').fadeTo(800,1,function(){

    //$(this).empty();
    //$(this)..append(data);                            

    //});
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**`slice()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) is by far [**the fastest way**](http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-gt-vs-not) you're going to be able to do this:

```
$('#user-table tr').slice(1).remove();
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhP6h/)

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin Well it's not going to work if you've changed your HTML.. you need to show me what it looks like :)

Comment: i ve changed it to table as #parentDiv and i want to delete all tr except the first one. there is no change when i do it

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin Use this then - `$('#parentDiv tr').slice(1).remove();`

Comment: i will write the script i jst did. check it above

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin You aren't using my code. Use this exact line - `$('#parentDiv tr').slice(1).remove();`. Do not insert a `>` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this -

```
$('#parentDiv > div:gt(0)').remove();
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/aaCam/

Answer (score 2):

I once was also on the same problem  and I fixed using:

```
$('#user-table > tr:not(:first)').remove();
```

you will also be done.